# How to implement class-validator as a middleware?

Tags: node.js, typescript, class-validator

I have been trying to use `class-validator` as middleware to validate some of my data.

I would love to get some advice as to

> how can I also validate updates and what's a good validation

Here is the current class validator to validate the `req.body` sent when trying to register.

```
export default async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  let user = new User();
  user.username = req.body.username;
  user.email = req.body.email;
  user.password = req.body.password;
  let fieldErrors = await validate(user);
  if (fieldErrors.length > 0) {
    let errors = ValidatorErrToFieldErr(fieldErrors);
    next(new HttpExeception({ statusCode: httpCode.BAD_REQUEST, errors }));
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

What is a good validation pattern? I controller that handles some of the logic which in turn calls the service to mutate the database.

AuthController.ts

```ts
public static Register = async (
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ) => {
    try {
      req.body.password = await argon2.hash(req.body.password);
      let modelUser = await service.addUser(req.body);
      let user: IUserMe = {
        //reasign user fields
      };
      req.session.user = {
        id: user.id,
        username: user.username,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      };

      res.json({ user });
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === "23505") {
        next(
          new HttpExeception({
            statusCode: httpCode.BAD_REQUEST,
            errors: duplicationErrToFieldError(error.detail),
          })
        );
      } else next(new HttpExeception({ statusCode: httpCode.SERVER_ERROR }));
    }
  };
```

UserService.ts

```ts
async addUser(input: IRegisterInput): Promise<User> {
    return await getRepository(User).save(input);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

So most middleware it’s called inside the routes themselves. I’ll use an example with Express, Passport, and TypeScript since it’s what I know best.

Say i don’t want users to access my “/home” page without signing in. So I write a middleware function:

```js
export default ( req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void => {
    if(req.user != undefined){
      next();
    }
   else{
      res.status(401);
   }
}
```

This would be analogous to your `class-validator` function. Now, we need to make sure that this function runs before any API calls are made to “/home”.

Thus, we write the api route as

```js
import * as express from “express”;
import {Request, Response} from “express”;
import isAuthenticated from “isAuthenticated.ts”;

class HomeRouter{
    public path = “/”;
    public router = App.router();

    constructor(){
        this.initRoutes();
    }

    public initRoutes(){
        this.router.get(“/home”, isAuthenticated, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
            res.send(“/index.html”);
       }
    }
}
```

This will force `isAuthenticated` to run before any of the logic in the rest of route is executed. If you would like the middleware to apply to every call to the server, just put `express.use(isAuthenticated);` in your server.ts file. If you’re using a technology different from Express that I’ve failed to identify, I’m sure the premise is the same, and the how will be in the documentation.